# Return from looping with list

Tags: python-3.x

this code almost same as Caesar cipher encrypt.
it just works when I just use convert(x, key) without return, but when I use return at function,
then I call with print(convert(x, key)), it just shows the last list not all.
It's possible return from looping on function?

```
x = int(input())
key = list(input())

def convert(a, b):
  for i in b:
    old = ord(i)
    old += a
    realvote = chr(old)
  return realvote
  print()
  
print(convert(x, key))
```

Input :

```
4
abc
```

Expect: efg

Output: g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a generator and the yield statement:

```
x = int(input())
key = list(input())

def convert(a, b):
  for i in b:
    old = ord(i)
    old += a
    realvote = chr(old)
    yield realvote
  
print(''.join(convert(x, key)))
```

Using purely strings:

```
x = int(input())
key = list(input())

def convert(a, b):
  retval = ""
  for i in b:
    old = ord(i)
    old += a
    retval += chr(old)
  return retval
  
print(convert(x, key))
```

One-liner:

```
convert = lambda a, b: "".join((chr(ord(c) + a) for c in b))
```

Comment: Thanks, Nico. I forget bout the yield xD